# Python 3: make a function go through all possible arguments without generating any errors

Tags: python, function, arguments, os.path

I want to open a file called text_file1.txt and see the content. That file can be located anywhere on the host machine, though it's in some subdirectory beneath /Users/BobbySpanks. 
In the code below roots will store all the absolute pathnames of subdirectories starting from /Users/BobbySpanks, but without a / at the end. I add a / and then text_file1.txt to all subdirectory pathanmes in roots in a variable called abs_path so that the file I want to read has a proper absolute pathname syntax.
So the problem is, I get a FileNotFound error when I try to open the file. I want the fo variable, which opens the file (using the absolute pathname), to go through all of the possible absolute pathnames that text_file1.txt can have. 
So I don't want the script to stop at the first possible absolute pathname, I want it to go through all of them until it finds the right pathname of text_file1.txt.

```
import os

filename = "text_file1.txt"

top_directory = r"/Users/BobbySpanks/"

for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(top_directory):
    ff = roots + "/"
    abs_path = ff + filename

file_open = open(abs_path, "r")
file_read = file_open.read()
print(file_read)
```

Comment: You should check if the file exists first. And if you want to find and process all such files, you'll need to put your file processing code in the loop

Comment: Check if your file is in ```files```; if it isn't continue; if it is use [```os.path.join```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to make the path with ```roots``` and the filename.